# Where is the Yabbok crossing?

Tags: geography, vayishlach

Where is the Yabbok crossing (mentioned in [Genesis 32:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227/jewish/Chapter-32.htm#v=23))?

Comment: Check the white Chumash with the fancy maps in it....what's it called? I think it's Mossad HaRav Kook.

Comment: ^^^^ Daas Mikrah Chumash (h/t [@YeZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18967867#18967867))

Comment: @Shokhet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da%27at_Miqra

Comment: Ypnypn, have you done any research yourself to try and find an answer? Why do you want to know this anyway (this could be relevant for what kind of resources and what formats or levels of precision are use in responding to you)?

Comment: @DoubleAA I did some very basic research (i.e. check some major commentators, etc.) but found zero so far. Just curious.

Comment: @Ypnypn You should always include information like that in the question itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It branches off the Jordan river, running eastward through Gilead, just north of Mt Nebo and to the south of the Bashan. Today it is known as the Wadi Zerqa ("Blue River"). See the maps on pages 38 and 115 of Anson Rainey and Steven Notley, *The Sacred Bridge* (Jerusalem: Carta, 2006), and the information in Randall W. Younker, "Jabbok" in Anchor Bible Dictionary III (New York: Doubleday, 1992), 593-594. See also Chaim Herzog and Mordechai Gichon, *Battles of the Bible* (Toronto: Stoddart Publishing, 1997), 69ff, for a description of Gideon's campaign against the Midianites, which followed this route - in particular, their map on p76.

Comment: +1 only thing this is missing is a picture

Comment: @user6591 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarqa_River#Biblical_Jabbok